# Householder Vector algorithm in Golub and Van Loan

Tags: linear-algebra, qr, householder

(This is repost of a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4585589/householder-vector-algorithm-in-golub-and-van-loan) first asked on Mathematics. Hopefully there are more people here who have a copy of Golub and Van Loan to hand)

In the 4th edition of "Matrix Computations", Golub and Van Loan present "Algorithm 5.1.1 (Householder Vector)". The first couple of lines (translated into MATLAB-syntax) read:

```
m = length(x); sigma = x(2:m)'*x(2:m); v = [1; x(2:m)];
if sigma == 0 && x(1) >= 0
  beta = 0;
elseif sigma == 0 && x(1) < 0
  beta = -2;
else
  ...
```

The `else` clause handles the case where `sigma` is nonzero and no code after the provided snippet modifies `v` if `sigma` is zero. The matrix form of the resulting Householder transformation is $I-\beta v v^T$.

The `elseif` clause is a little strange. It doesn't appear in the algorithm listing in the
3rd edition, so it was added for the 4th, presumably for numerical stability. However, it seems to me to generate a $(\beta, v)$ pair that doesn't map to an orthogonal matrix. For example, if `x = [-1; 0; 0]` then `sigma == 0` and `x(1) < 0` so we get `beta = -2` and `v = [1; 0; 0]` and a Householder transformation of `[3, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1]` which is not an orthogonal matrix.

So my questions are:

- What benefit is there to handling that case separately, rather than just setting `beta = 0` if `sigma = 0`?
- Does the resulting Householder transformation need to be applied differently?

Comment: This was also shortly implemented in LAPACK and led to strange errors. The apparent problem is that the QR decomposition of the unit matrix is with the earlier and later algorithm $Q=-I$, $R=-I$. Someone had the splendid idea to correct this, and possibly the problem of negative entries on the diagonal of $R$, on the basis of the reflector encoding, but one can see easily that this leads to numerical instability.

Comment: Honestly I'd consider writing Van Loan and asking. Although I only have the 3rd edition of the book, I feel it's generally careful about numerical stability and am surprised that it would perform these steps in the algorithm without some accompanying justification in the text. If it is indeed unstable, as indicated by someone trying it in LAPACK and flopping, I think an email raising the issue so that it can be added to the errata would be welcomed.

Comment: Updated my answer in math.SE. This is an actual error in the code (after having seen a complete listing), but probably won't get hit except for carefully constructed test examples. More problematic is that floating point noise for input vectors around the $e_1$ axis gets magnified to a point on the equator for the reflector normal. This kind of randomness goes counter the idea of numerical stability.

Comment: @rchilton1980 : This was years ago, was discussed, I even wrote a bug report (probably too late, it vanished somewhere), but the code was rolled back to the 3rd edition or standard version. This was proudly [announced in Lapack 3.2 (11/16/2008)](https://netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.2.html#_9_3_non_negative_diagonals_from_householder_qr). There was then a [partial roll-back based on a bug report by Pat Quillen (MathWorks)](https://icl.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php%3Ff=2&t=1986.html) due to reduced accuracy and overflow problems.

Comment: cont. An apparently real [head-scratcher with example code and data](https://icl.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php%3Ff=2&t=1783.html) was reported in Mar 16, 2010. While the internet is forever, points of interest seem to become inaccessible 10 to 15 years later.